# body click issue with highchart library

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have created a popup which hides when i click on body. but in hightchart the body click is not working.

Hightchart Library:
http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js

My jQuery Code is:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +'°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
    });

    $("body").click(function(){
      $(".popupBox").hide();  
    });
    $(".popup").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
     $(".popupBox").toggle();      
    });
});​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Divya_Moyal/3jLtE/1/)

Thanks in advance for the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call click event of 'container' div because all the child element of 'container' div preventing click event bubbling up the DOM tree.

So you have to call mousedown event instead of click.

```
$(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'}]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ': ' + this.y + '°C';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]},
        {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]},
        {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]},
        {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]}]
    });
    });
    $("html").click(function() {
       $(".popupBox").hide();
    });
    $(".popup").click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       $(".popupBox").toggle();
    });
    $("#container").mousedown(function(e) {
       $(".popupBox").hide();
    });
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yoku2010/8R7Kx/)

Comment: @DivyaMoyal how is this different from my answer (which was posted way before)?

Comment: @JugalThakkar: solution is same.. but yoku2010 explaining me the reason why i have to use mousedown instead of click and why click was not working here...

Answer (score 2):

You can handle this in the [`mousedown`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event of the chart container

```
$("#container").mousedown(function(){
      $(".popupBox").hide();      
});
```

This will be triggered on any mousebutton, you can check the button and handle as you wish using the `which` property of the eventObject passed on to the handler

```
$("#container").mousedown(function(e){
      if(e.which==1){ // Only on left click
         $(".popupBox").hide();      
      }
});
```

**[Handling chart container click event | Highchart & Highstock](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/qXSf5)**
**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/qXSf5/1/)**

Comment: perfect.. i was struggling from two days :)  .. highcharts is awful and great also

Answer (score 1):

Its not about script refrence. Its about chart click event. I added click event to chart and it works.

```
 chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25,

            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    $(".popupBox").hide();
                }

            },
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jLtE/18/